# Why can't I hire the Knights Templar?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

[image]

There's a Crusade for Greece on at the moment, and I'd like to hire some Holy Orders.  I have plenty of Piety, but for some reason the "Hire" buttons of all the Holy Orders are greyed out.

For what it's worth, the Teutonic Order are "Under contract with the Knights Hospitaller in Eilat", so I can see that'd make them unavailable.  But what about the Knights Templar?

What's going on?

**Edit:**

Hmmm, fast forward a few months and the Templars and Hospitaller are now both available for hire (though the Templars have been badly mangled, so I guess I'll let them recover before hiring them).

Comment: Have you checked if they're part of the Crusade? There are numerous cases where they seem to get the Crusade goal when the Crusade is won, which suggests they take part normally.

Comment: @thegrinner Yeah, I think they were part of the crusade, but that's just from looking at where their leader was.

Answer (score 1):

If a Holy order is busy fighting a war in personal capacity i.e. in your case, this crusade as thegrinner suggested about three years ago, then they aren't available to be hired by other rulers.

They are already a co-belligerent in the war so employment by any ruler in midst of that would cause internal logical errors. Who gets their war contribution score?

You can easily check that in the list of participants of the crusades. An easy way to overcome this is make up your mind early enough. As soon as crusade is declared, send a missive to the pope with request to join him and hire the available orders before someone else does or before they decide to get busy themselves.